# Path problems in write18-call after miktex-update

Tags: paths, shell-escape, miktex-update

After updating miktex on 2021/04/18 I realized a changed behaviour when using
write18-calls from within TeX.

In one of my source files I have the line

```
\immediate\write18{ skizze.bat  1 mp }
```

and with the newly installed executable

> pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (MiKTeX 21.3) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.4.20)

I got the error-message (on the console)

> Der Befehl "skizze.bat" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
> konnte nicht gefunden werden.

Within the TeX-logfile one reads

> runsystem(skizze.bat 1 mp)...executed.

which shows that write18 is enabled.

The batch-file 'skizze.bat' lies in 'd:\batch' and this directory is part of my
(global) path. Apparently in the new installation the write18-command does not
know this system-path. With a minimal example I found that in the shell called
by write18 one only has

> PATH=d:\TeX\MiKTeX2.9\miktex\bin\x64

However with my old executable

> pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 2.9.7380 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.4.18)

all went well.

Thanks for help Norbert Klingen

Comment: I just tried to execute a batch file in my path and it works fine. Perhaps your editor resets the path.

Comment: So it was for me before updating. My editor is stand-alone (PE32) and has no connection to the LaTeX-call from the command line.

Comment: well as I said, I can't reproduce it, but if you think it is a miktex bug, open an issue at the miktex github.

Comment: Thanks for dealing with the question. I asked the same question on miktex github but got the same answer 'all works well', but unfortunately no hint what might have gone wrong with the update. So I made a try whether here someone would have an idea or even a similar problem. Thanks again for dealing with my question.

Comment: I must say I absolutly love it when questions leave out important data. Don't you think that it would have been nice and sensible to mention that you made already a miktex bug report? I have no idea if it is related but all your cmd line screenshots show that you load an external library clink.

Comment: I accept your critics and have to apologize.

Comment: Do you have anything in your Autorun registry key. Check by opening the Registry Editor (Windows Key + R, type regedit, press enter), then in the box at the top copy and paste `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor`. Check if there is something in the Autorun key.

Comment: You should also check `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor`

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue in that MiKTeX appeared to be overriding my path variable. This caused any packages that needed the `--shell-escape` or `write18` feature to fail. I discovered the issue was because I was using [clink v0.4.9](https://github.com/mridgers/clink) which was set to autorun in every instance of the shell.

This only applies if you are using Windows. (In the original question and [bug report](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/786), the OP didn't mention what OS they had. I assume from their Path variable that it is Windows).

## Solution 1: Uninstall Clink / Remove anything from your Autorun registry key

### Uninstall Clink

Open a command prompt, type `clink autorun show`.
My output was

```
Current AutoRun values

  Current user:

    native : "C:\Program Files (x86)\clink\0.4.9\clink.bat" inject --autorun --profile ~\clink
     wow64 : "C:\Program Files (x86)\clink\0.4.9\clink.bat" inject --autorun --profile ~\clink

  All users:

    native : <unset>
     wow64 : <unset>
```

Now run `clink autorun uninstall`. You should see

```
Current AutoRun values

  Current user:

    native : <unset>
     wow64 : <unset>

  All users:

    native : <unset>
     wow64 : <unset>

Clink's autorun entry has been removed (for current user).
```

### Manually Remove from Registry

Open the registry editor (Windows Key + R, type regedit, press enter), then in the box at the topy copy and paste `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor`. In the right pane, if there is an entry titled "Autorun", double click on it, make the box under "Value data", click OK. Repeat the process for `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor`. If there is no entry for "Autorun" skip it.

## Solution 2: Install the new version of clink

Clink v0.4.9 was released in Dec 20, 2017 so it is quite outdated (at the time of writing). There is a fork of the project that is being maintained. See https://github.com/chrisant996/clink. Uninstall the old version by going to Start Menu -> Add or Remove Progams. Navigate to Clink v0.4.9 and click uninstall. Then go to the maintained fork's [releases page](https://github.com/chrisant996/clink/releases) to download and install the new version.

## Test to make sure everything worked

Create a file name `test.tex` with the following contents.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter 
\immediate\write18{echo \@percentchar PATH\@percentchar > tmp.txt}
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

Run in a command prompt, open in the same folder of the file you just created, and run `pdflatex --shell-escape test.tex`. Open tmp.txt, it should have the correct PATH variable now.